# How to insert a character inside a string at a fixed position from the end?

Tags: php

Example: `845`, `945`, `1045`, `1145`.

If the length of the string is 3 then I am trying to add a `:` after the first character, e.g. `8:45`. If the length of the string is 4 then I am trying to add `:` after the second character, e.g. `10:45`. Not sure which method would help me do that. Any suggestions?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $message = $row['Timings'];

    if(strlen($message) = 3)
        {

        } 
    else if(strlen($message) = 4)
        {

        }
```

Comment: When you compare two values in PHP, you must use the `==` (equality) or the `===` (identity) operator. The `=` (assignment) operator is used to set the value of a variable.

Comment: Hi Sharanya you are right i realized it when i got an error. i got it fixed anyways thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$message = substr($message, 0, -2).":".substr($message, -2);
```